# Php custom date format and comparison

Tags: php, database, date, format, comparison

In my database I have one table in which I keep registered users.
One column is Date of register and I keep this value in my own string format.
For example "[2013-11-30] [19:42:46]"

Then I want to make a check.
If user is 30 days old or more.
The sure thing is that the above code is wrong.
The problem is that if one user registers at 29/01/2015
will not been showing in 30 last days if the current day is 02/02/2015!

```
//Datetime
   $today = date_parse_from_format("[Y-m-d] [H:i:s]", gmdate("[Y-m-d] [H:i:s]"));
   $store = date_parse_from_format("[Y-m-d] [H:i:s]", $row["LastSeen"]);

   if (
        (($store[year] >= $today[year]) && ($store[month] >= $today[month]))
      )
   { $date_last = "<font color='green'>".$row["LastSeen"]."</font>"; }
   else
   { $date_last = "<font color='red'>".$row["LastSeen"]."</font>"; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date_create_from_format` instead of `date_parse_from_format`. Then you can simply compare the resulting values:

```
$today = date_create_from_format("[Y-m-d] [H:i:s]", gmdate("[Y-m-d] [H:i:s]"));
$store = date_create_from_format("[Y-m-d] [H:i:s]", $row["LastSeen"]);

if ($store < $today) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i also tried this and date_create_from_format doesn't work!